# Push value in Array in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to push values in an Array in IndexedDB. But it seems like the put() method replaces / overrides the existing data.

```js
const idbPromise = async() => {
  try {
    const db = await openDB("first", 1, {
      // dbx, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction
      upgrade(dbx) {
        if (!dbx.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
          dbx.createObjectStore("data", {
            keyPath: "name"
          });
        }
      }
    });

    return db;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};


const appendData = async(value) => {
  return idbPromise()
    .then(function(db) {
      const tx = db.transaction("data", "readwrite");
      const store = tx.objectStore("data");
      store.put(data);
      return tx.complete;
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

// first call
appendData({
  name: "arr",
  value: [1]
});

// second call
appendData({
  name: "arr",
  value: [2]
});
```

The output of the code above is `value: [2]` but I want to achieve `value: [1,2]`.
How would I achieve this?

PS: I don't want to copy and the existing values and add all of it, I want it to work like JavaScript's `push()` method.

Comment: You might not want to, but that is how it works... you can only replace an object in an object store

Answer (score 0):

As Josh suggested only way to do append is to read the object and then update it - here is a sample written with pure js as I don't have the openDb script which you are using.

```js
const appendData = (newValue) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const request = indexedDB.open("todos");
        request.onsuccess = (e) => {
            const db = e.target.result;
            const trans = db.transaction(["data"],"readwrite");
            const store = trans.objectStore("data");

            const openCursorReq = store.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(newValue.name));
            openCursorReq.onsuccess = (event) => {
                const cursor = event.target.result;
                let oldValue = cursor.value;
                oldValue.value = oldValue.value.concat(newValue.value);
                var updateRequest = cursor.update(oldValue);
                updateRequest.onerror = updateRequest.onblocked = () => {
                    
                    console.log('Error updating');
                    reject();
                };

                updateRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
                    console.log('update', newValue);
                    resolve();
                };

                trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
                    db.close();
                };
            }
        };
        request.onerror = reject;
    })
};
```